# Just add new (different) elements to the array in Ruby (Rails)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I want to create an array in Rails that contains every value of two columns but each just one time. So, for example, there is in column "A" `{1,5,7,1,7}` and in column "B" `{3,2,3,1,4}`.

When I just wanted an array with all elements of "A", I would write:

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:A)
```

And I would get `{1,5,7}`.

Is there an option in Rails to make the same thing with two columns, so just getting all values one time that are contained in two columns? (Here it would be `{1,5,7,3,2,4}`)

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no such thing in Ruby as `{1, 5, 7, 1, 7}`. What is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, pass multiple column names to [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck):

```
Model.pluck(:A, :B)
#=> [[1, 3], [5, 2], [7, 3], [1, 1], [7, 4]]
```

But of course you want the values together and uniqued so:

```
Model.pluck(:A, :B).flatten.uniq
#=> [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4]
```

Doing `Model.uniq.pluck(:A, :B).flatten` won’t work since it will just get distinct *rows* (i.e. combinations of A & B), so you’d still have to `uniq` again after flattening.

Comment: *+1*..to help me for remembering this method..:)

Comment: Sorry, I have to take it back, because rails always complains about givng two arguments to "pluck", how can I solve this?

Comment: @AntonKan Upgrade to Rails/ActiveRecord 4. AR 3.2 only supported one column being given to `pluck`—you didn’t specify a version so I assumed the latest. Alternatively you can do them separately and concatenate them: `(Model.pluck(:A) + Model.pluck(:B)).uniq`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the point, I used the concate method. I think I have to upgrade but not today ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
records = []
Model.all.map {|e| records << [e.A, e.B] }
uniq_records = records.flatten.uniq
```

Hope this would help you.

Thanks

Comment: The performance of this is less than great as it requires creating model instances for every record (which `pluck` won’t do).

Comment: The performance could be terrible with a big table. Retrieving unique records is a common database action and should be done in the database to reduce the load on the database, the network and on the Ruby app, plus both the DB and application hosts.